# Async await promise pending

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a function that adds and returns the next highest value from a mysql table row based on a search criteria. My function looks like:

```
    async function getNextNumber(systemType){
        let newCounter
        try{
            if(systemType == 'POS'){
                await pool.query(`Update counters set value = value + 1 where type = 'POS'`)
                let newCounter == await pool.query(`Select value from counters where type = 'POS'`)
                console.log(newCounter)
            }

            if(systemType == 'ST'){
                await pool.query(`Update counters set value = value + 1 where type = 'ST'`)
                let newCounter = await pool.query(`Select value from counters where type = 'ST'`)
            }



            return newCounter
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }


    }



console.log(getNextNumber('POS'))
```

This gives me:

> Promise { pending}
>
> [ RowDataPacket { value: 101 } ]

I wanted the `[ RowDataPacket { value: 101 } ]` result where it says promise pending.

I also tried:

```
async function test(){
    console.log(await getNextNumber('QC'))
}
```

This gives me no result

Comment: Why don't you try with POS as arguments cause Qc will return null

Comment: an `async` function is guaranteed to return a `Promise` - because that is how `async` functions are defined in the javascript specification! It seems to be a common misconception that `async` can give you an asynchronous result synchronously ... the keyword is `async`, not `sync`

Comment: Are you using `mysql` library? because the library is based on callbacks and not promises

Comment: Yes I am but I also used the promisfy lib to promisify the mysql lib. With the suggestions from the accepted answer below, the code is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several coding errors:

1. Only your first declaration of `let newCounter` should have the `let` in front of it.  When you then assign `newCounter` a value, remove the `let`.  That is creating a new locally scoped (to the local block) variable, assigning a value to it and then it goes out of scope and the top level `newCounter` never gets a value.
2. Assignment is done with `=`, not with `==` unless all you want in the variable is a boolean.  So change `let newCounter == await pool.query(...)` to just `newCounter == await pool.query(...)`.
3. All `async` functions return a promise and you HAVE to use `.then()` or `await` on the returned promise from calling `getNextNumber()`.  So, your second try with `console.log(await getNextNumber('QC'))` should work once you fix the other coding errors.

And, then one more thing to check.

Are you 100% sure that your version of your database is returning a promise from `pool.query()`?  `await` ONLY does something useful if the value you are awaiting is a promise and it contains no magic to make other types of asynchronous operations actually wait and return a value.  `await` needs to be used with a promise.

---

Putting this together (and assuming you're using the right `pool.query()` interface that returns a promise:

```
async function getNextNumber(systemType) {
    let newCounter;
    try {
        if (systemType == 'POS') {
            await pool.query(`Update counters set value = value + 1 where type = 'POS'`);
            newCounter = await pool.query(`Select value from counters where type = 'POS'`);
            console.log(newCounter);
        } else if (systemType == 'ST') {
            await pool.query(`Update counters set value = value + 1 where type = 'ST'`);
            newCounter = await pool.query(`Select value from counters where type = 'ST'`);
        } else {
            // probably need some other return value or error handling here
            throw new Error("invalid systemType in getNextNumber()")
        }
        return newCounter;

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        throw err;            // need to propagate the error
    }

}

console.log(await getNextNumber('POS'));

// or with error handling
getNextNumber('POS').then(val => {
    console.log(val);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Ah i knew i should rethrow, If we just rethrow should we just omit the catch block and handle it when we call the function ?

Comment: @AsafAviv - You can just remove the `catch()` block in `getNextNumber()` if you don't want to log the error there.  The error will propagate to a rejected promise returned from `getNextNumber()` and the caller can catch it as I showed.

Comment: Thank you learned a lot from this. To answer your question I am certain that pool.query returns a promise as I have used `.then` as well as `async and await` to consume the promise before and you code works perfectly as well

Comment: Also I almost always use `console.log(err)` instead of `throw(err)`. From your code where you have commented  // need to propagate the error, I google searched "async await propagate error" but did not find anything useful. Can you please point me somewhere where I can read about what you mean by propagate error?

Comment: @jedu - Propagate the error means to allow the caller to see the error. Your code hid the error from the caller of your function by allowing the returned promise to be resolved with no value instead of rejected with the error as the reason.